# Calculating total possible Fantasy Football lineup combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a fantasy football roster that is made up of:

- K. Cousins (QB)
- B. Bortles (QB)
- A. Smith (QB)
- M. Evans (WR)
- D. Baldin (WR)
- J. Brown (WR)
- T. Smith (WR)
- L. McCoy (RB)
- D. Johnson (RB)
- M. Forte (RB)
- R. Gronkowski (TE)
- C. Walford (TE)
- J. Tucker (K)
- Green Bay (DEF)

In total, 3 QB's, 4 WR's, 3 RB's, 2 TE's, 1 K, and 1 DEF

I am trying to calculate how many unique possible lineup combinations I can create from this roster, with the lineup that consists of:

- 1 QB
- 2 WR
- 2 RB
- 1 TE
- 1 FLEX (WR or RB)
- 1 Kicker
- 1 Defense

My issue is with the Flex position. If I have a roster where D. Baldwin starts at WR, and M. Evans starts at Flex, and another roster where D. Baldin starts at Flex and M. Evans starts at WR (flip of the first scenario), that is not a unique roster. How do I calculate for this?

Comment: Do you mean that Baldwin-WR and Evans-Flex is counted as a different lineup than Baldwin-Flex and Evans-WR, or are they counted as the same?

Comment: They are counted as the same - if Evans-Flex, and Baldwin-WR - that is the same as if Baldin-Flex and Evans-WR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 choices for QB and 2 choices for TE.

1) If the Flex is a RB, then you have $\binom{3}{3}$ choices for RB and  $\binom{4}{2}$ choices for WR,

$\;\;\;$giving $3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot6=36$ lineups.

2) If the Flex is a WR, then you have $\binom{3}{2}$ choices for RB and 
$\binom{4}{3}$ choices for WR,

$\;\;\;$giving $3\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4=72$ lineups.

Therefore you have a total of 108 possible lineups.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate combinations for the two "ground" lineups (with FLEX resolved to one of the two values). As these lineups do not intersect, you can add these two numbers up to get the total number.

Comment: So, calculate the 3RB/2WR and 2RB/3WR lineups and add them together for total number of 2RB/2WR/1FLEX?  Looks like a good idea to me.

Comment: Yes. Note that it is important that their extents are non-overlapping, as otherwise you wouldn't be able to just add them.

Comment: So is the answer 108 then? Calculating 3WR/2RB (3*4*3*2*1*1) = 72, and calculating 3RB/2WR (3*6*1*2*1*1) = 36